# Remove all pathcomponents from a URL in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurl

I have a URL with a number of path components. Is there an elegant way to remove all path components? Basically, I just want to keep the scheme and the host of the URL. And the port, if available.

I can of course create a new URL object, using the relevant properties from the existing URL:

```
let newURL = "\(existingURL.scheme!)://\(existingURL.host!)"
```

Or loop over the pathcomponents, removing the last component, until none remains.

But both of these solutions doesn't seem that elegant, so I'm looking for a better, safer and more efficient solution.

Comment: can you give example to output you need

Comment: Looking into the docs there isn't anything like that.

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish Let's say I have a URL like "http://www.somedomain.com/with/some/path/components". I would like to remove the "/with/some/path/components" part of the URL, and just keep "http://www.somedomain.com"

Comment: you can use regex answer added , used with any url

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only possibility I see is to use `URLComponents` and manually remove some components:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com/and/my/path")!
print(url)

var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
components.path = ""
print(components.url!) // http://www.google.com
```

If you decide to build URL manually, it's probably still better to use `URLComponents` for that:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com/and/my/path")!
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = url.scheme
components.host = url.host
print(components.url!) // http://www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Regex method. It will be more elegant than other ways. I just did quick code. Regex might not work but you will get lot more regex examples for your type of query.

```
    let urlRegEx = "((http(s)?:\\(/)\\/)|(\\/.*){1}"
    let string = "https://pixabay.com/en/art-beauty-fairytales-fantasy-2436545/"
    let matched = matches(for: urlRegEx, in: string)
    print(matched)

   func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reg-EX

```
  let url = "http://www.somedomain.com/?f"
                let pattern = "^(http://|https://)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?!.*\\|\\w*$)"
                 let regex = try! NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
                let matches = regex.matches(in: url, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, url.count))

                matches.enumerated().forEach({ (_, match) in
                    print((url as NSString).substring(with: match.range))
                })
```